# What are the differences between the various character types?

Tags: mario-tennis-open

With the exception of the Mii, each of the characters fall into one of the following types:

- All-Around
- Technique
- Speed
- Tricky
- Power
- Defense

I'm sure each of these are meant to convey useful information about the stats of each character, however I have no idea what each of them means, and the manual doesn't appear to contain any information on this.

What do the various character types mean?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: I've rolled back your edit. Please see [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless/4639#4639) for details as to why.

Comment: Is that actually a canonical rule, or just a proposal? It's a shame because I like to browse tags like `3ds` (I just find it interesting; I understand that I wouldn't be able to answer every question in the tag).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: That's a proposal which has become the new status quo, but even with the old rules platform tags were not supposed to be used just because the game was on that platform, only if it was about the platform or the game had multiple versions (and the platform mattered for the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All-Around** is, well, all-around. The character doesn't stand out in any of its areas but it isn't bad in any of its areas.
**Technique** characters specialize in ball control.
**Speed** characters are faster than others but have weaker shots.
**Tricky** characters have shots that curve the ball when they hit, especially Slice shots.
**Power** characters are slower than others but have stronger shots.
**Defense** characters can hit the ball well from most positions.

Comment: I've played around with each of the types some more, and your descriptions due seem to match the differences I've noted as well.